# ELK Deployment; CPU,Memory,Disk

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I would like to deploy Elasticsearch, logstash and kibana in 3 different flavors, the characteristics of each one:
o 32vCPU, 384Go RAM et 900Go HDD

I would like to supervise 100 servers so approximately 33 servers in each flavors.

Do you think it's a good idea to use this configuration? and it's not a problem to use this huge capacity of memory?
Another question how many nodes should I use?

Answer (score 2):

without details its hard to give you global advice but Elasticsearch recommend to never cross 31Gb for RAM. [Here are the reasons why](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#compressed_oops)

You should read all the page, they explain why it is generally far better to have a lot of small/medium hosts instead of a few big ones.

I also recommend you to read [this post](https://thoughts.t37.net/designing-the-perfect-elasticsearch-cluster-the-almost-definitive-guide-e614eabc1a87), it will give you some insight on how to design an Elastic Cluster especially the distinction between roles in a cluster and the difference in hardware needed.

For your question :

> Another question how many nodes should I use?

There is no good answer without knowing the volume of data, read/write etc etc...

And last, I hardly doubt that using the same configuration for kibana / logstash / elastic hosts is a good idea. They just don't do the same sort of processing. You should start with small configuration and update it incrementally when you will have real data.

Comment: Oh I see! so it's better to use for example a small machine with only 8 vCPUs,64GB RAM, and 250 Go HDD? In fact I would like to store data from different servers each one generate between 1go and 10 go per day, and I would like to store the data 7 days. That's why I would know if logstash can index data from (5-10 servers) and how many nodes should I use to configure Elasticsearch.ps: each server generate between 20-100 files/minutes .

Comment: You will only know after trying i think, I have not enough experience with logstash to give you advice on that, sorry :(